# Connecting std::set<T> to a memory pool

Tags: c++

I am currently experimenting with custom allocators. I have a [small application](https://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PlayGroundCpp/MemoryPool/main.cpp) that implements a custom allocator with a memory pool.

It works with `std::vector` but when I try it with `std::set` I get a runtime error:

```
typedef std::set<Data, std::less<Data>, my_allocator<Data> > PoolSet;

Pool<Data> pool(1024);    
PoolSet set;
set.insert(Data()); // error: no pool found for type: std::_Rb_tree_node<Data>
```

The problem is that std::set uses my allocator for both the data and the data-node. Since there is no pool registered for the data-node the code will fail.

The details can be found in the [code](https://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PlayGroundCpp/MemoryPool/main.cpp).

Does anyone know what I do to get around this?

Comment: Are you wanting the map internal data structures to be pooled?  If not, I guess you could define `my_allocator::rebind` in such a way as would return a `std::allocator`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `rebind` mentioned by @BenVoigt.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B))

> Allocators are required to supply a
>   template class member `template
>   <typename U> struct A::rebind {
>   typedef A<U> other; };`, which enables
>   the possibility of obtaining a related
>   allocator, parametrized in terms of a
>   different type. For example, given an
>   allocator type `IntAllocator` for
>   objects of type `int`, a related
>   allocator type for objects of type
>   `long` could be obtained using
>   `IntAllocator::rebind<long>::other`.